# use of -p while calling a python script from shell

Tags: python, shell

I am working on a project where python scripts are called from shell script. The syntax is quite straight forward.

*python3 ./importmetrics.py -p $value*

What I am struggling it to find the use of "-p" before passing the argument.

Comment: The specific Python script defines the meaning of "-p" here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Satish. It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking here - could you maybe rephrase the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.